# QGis 2.18 Actions window does not display 'Actions Properties'

Tags: qgis, actions

I have installed QGis 2.18.19 64bits in Windows 7. My problem is when I open the layer properties actions window, I do not see the menu Action Properties.
Apparently it should be there according to the QGis documentation (e.g. QGis 2.18 training manual). What I am missing.

I also noticed that the button is named "Create default actions" while in the guide is named "Add default actions"

Here is my screen capture:

[image]

Here is the capture of the training manual pdf image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can double click on an action to edit its detail. This edit window has the same attributes as in the tutorial.

[image]